# Changing class on hover

Tags: jquery

I have a list of elements:

```
<div class="item someitem"></div>
<div class="item another1"></div>
<div class="item one_more"></div>
```

I need to be able change the second class on hover from "thisitem" to "thisitem_hover".

```
$('.item').hover(
    function() {
        // add '_hover'
    }, function() {
        // remove '_hover'
    }
);
```

How do I do something like this?

Comment: addClass and removeClass ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should add '_hover' on the second class on your div elements.

```
$('.item').hover(function() {
  var klass = $(this).attr("class").replace("item ", "")
  $(this).toggleClass(klass + " " + klass + "_hover");
});
```

**Note that**, for this to work, you must have only two classes, viz. `item` and the generated CSS class.

Comment: How would I know which class I toggle? The divs are generated dynamically.

Comment: you mean that you want to change `another1` to `another1_hover` in your examples and not `item` to `item_hover` ?

Comment: That's correct. Second class in the example is specific to each div. I just need to append '_hover' to each and every one of those unique divs on hover, and remove when the mouse rolls out.

Answer (score 2):

Try [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$('.item').hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('thisitem thisitem_hover')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6xHX8/)

Comment: Hmm... must be lacking caffeine -- over thinking simple things. Sorry, the divs did not show-up. I've edited now.